# Validation data separate from training data TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When training a model with TensorFlow 2 as shown below, should the validation data be separated from the training data before it is passed to the model's `fit` method, or can it be part of the training set? At the end of the code below show two options. I would believe option 1 is the correct, but as I have seen some sources using option 2 I want to make sure I understand it correctly.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, series_y)

best_weight_path = 'best_weights.hdf5'

numpy_x = df_x.to_numpy()
numpy_y = series_y.to_numpy()

numpy_x_train = X_train.to_numpy()
numpy_y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
numpy_x_test = X_test.to_numpy()
numpy_y_test = y_test.to_numpy()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=best_weight_path, verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
```

**option 1**

```
model.fit(numpy_x_train, numpy_y_train, validation_data=(numpy_x_test, numpy_y_test), callbacks=[monitor, checkpointer], verbose=0, epochs=1000)
```

**option 2**

```
model.fit(numpy_x, numpy_y, validation_data=(numpy_x_test, numpy_y_test), callbacks=[monitor, checkpointer], verbose=0, epochs=1000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first option is correct... you split before the data and use your train to fit and evaluate on test/valid

the second option no... you are putting all your data to train while are passing a subpart of them for evaluation. Keras is not so clever to understand this. but to achieve what u are looking for in this second option u simply need `validation_split = 0.xxx`

```
model.fit(numpy_x, numpy_y, validation_split=0.xxx, callbacks=[monitor, checkpointer], verbose=0, epochs=1000)
```

in other words, u pass ALL your data in fit and then Keras operate a random split of them using a 0.xxx % for evaluation/testing